# Vulnerability test for CVE-2014-7169 (Shellshock)

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, shellshock

I found [this test here](https://gist.github.com/KalenAnson/231db4b468fc53a5ae7d) for the Shellshock vulnerability follow-up [CVE-2014-7169](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-7169) , which is basicaly doing:

```
echo `env X='() { (a)=>\' sh -c "echo '[Vulnerability CVE-2014-7169 Detected]'" 2> /dev/null; cat echo 2> /dev/null`
```

Is this the correct way to test the vulnerability? And why does it involve `sh` and not `bash`?

My default shell is bash on one server:

```
ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Okt 18  2013 /bin/sh -> bash
```

and `dash` on another, where the test is also positive.

(if that's a problem, would it cause problems if I changed the default shell??)

Comment: The part that includes `sh` is a piece of the payload, not the exploit.

Comment: Maybe a false positive? https://github.com/hannob/bashcheck/issues/6#issuecomment-57081774